# Docker taking up a lot of disk space

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows on Windows 10.

I was experiencing issues with system SSD always being full and moved 'docker-desktop-data' distro (which is used to store docker images and other stuff) out of the system drive to drive D: which is HDD using [this guide](https://dev.to/kimcuonthenet/move-docker-desktop-data-distro-out-of-system-drive-4cg2).

Finally, I was happy to have a lot of space on my SSD... but docker containers started to work slower. I guess this happens due to HDD write/read operations being slower than on SSD.

Is there a better way to solve the problem of the continuously growing size of Docker distro's without impacting how fast containers actually work and images are built?

Answer (score 1):

Actually only be design. As you know, a docker container is layered. So it might be feasible to check if it is possible to create something like a "base-container" from which your actual image in derived.
Also it might be sensible to check if your base distro is small enough. I often have seen containers created from full blown Debian or Ubuntu distros. Thats not the best idea. Try to derive from an alpine version or check for even smaller approaches.